# Найти элементы с ключем меньшим заданнного. Multimap

Tags: c++, поиск, map, key

Каким образом можно получить(найти) элемент, введя через консоль переменную `int k`, и получив `auto itr`, чтобы исполнился код по поиску элементов с наименьшим ключом? Или это как-то вообще по другому надо реализовать?
ps Извините и поймите, если что-то коряво и тп, новичок.

```
int main() {
    multimap<int, int> myMultimap;

    for (;;) {
    //...
        case  3: { //Поиск первого элемента с ключом, меньшим заданному ключу
            cout << "Задайте ключ, чтобы найти элементы с ключом, меньшим заданному ключу:\n";
            cin >> k;

            //То что я написал и пытаюсь исполнить для поиска элементов с наименьшим ключом
            multimap<int, int>::key_compare comp = myMultimap.key_comp();
            //auto itr = myMultimap.find(k);
            multimap<char, int>::iterator itr = myMultimap.find(k);
            auto it = myMultimap.begin();
            do {
                cout << (*it).first << " : " << (*it).second << '\n';
            } while (comp((*it++).first, itr));


            //пытался сделать что-то такое, но не такое...
            //for (auto it = myMultimap.begin(); it < myMultimap(i); ++it)
            //{
            //  cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;
            //}
        }
    ///...
}
```

Comment: https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/lower_bound

Comment: Если все элементы с ключем меньше заданного (это из заголовка вопроса), то как-то так -- `for (auto it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.end() && (*it).first < k; it++) { ... }`, поскольку итератор `.begin()` указывает на минимальный элемент в multimap / Дальнейший текст в вопросе несколько сбивает, не слишком ясно, что же вам реально надо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Перебор всех элементов с ключом, *строго меньше* `k`:

```
for(auto it = myMultimap.begin(); it != myMultimap.lower_bound(k); ++it)
{
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << '\n';
}
```

Все, вам не нужно мучиться и сравнивать самостоятельно... В принципе, для ускорения можно написать

```
for(auto end = myMultimap.lower_bound(k), it = myMultimap.begin(); it != end; ++it)
```

Описание `lower_bound` - [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/lower_bound).

Answer (score 2):

```
auto it = myMultimap.begin()
for (; it != myMultimap.end() && it->first < k; it++) 
{
    cout << it->first << " : " << it->second << endl;
}
```

Итераторы нельзя сравнить на больше или меньше, а только на равенство.

Либо же, можно сразу найти итератор на элемент, ключ которого меньше k.

```
 auto it = myMultimap.lower_bound(k-1);
```

Comment: а почему вы итератор на первый элемент из for выносите? не понимаю зачем так некоторые делают, обьясните пожалуйста